# Clarify understanding of VirtualBox snapshots re deleting

Tags: virtualbox, snapshot

As part of testing installation and function of an application, I deploy it to a fresh VirtualBox guest each time. In order to do this, I first installed a fresh copy of the guest OS into the VM and then made a snapshot, the intent being to revert to this snapshot before each test run.

However, there was one small change I made after that event (I always seem to miss *something*). This was the mounting of the host drive so that I could keep my test scripts and application data there and just run a single command on the guest to kick off and report on everything.

So I made those changes, took another snapshot, and the situation is now:

```
Baseline (22 days ago)
|
+- HostMounted (21 days ago)
   |
   +- Current state
```

Since I don't need the baseline any more, and my build system takes up a *huge* amount of space, I'd like to get rid of it. However, being the paranoid type, I wanted to confirm:

Will deleting the `Baseline` snapshot still leave me with an identical `HostMounted`? I'm basically looking to ensure that I end up with:

```
HostMounted (21 days ago)
|
+- Current state
```

I've looked at the doco and various posts on discussion groups but they seem ambiguous to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `HostMounted` snapshot can be considered a standalone one. Deleting other snapshots will not change it in any way.

In other words, even if snapshots were stored as a simple difference between the previous state and the snapshot, deleting the previous state would roll any necessary changes into that snapshot.

This is supported by the [VirtualBox documentation](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#snapshots) (my emphasis):

> You can restore a snapshot by right-clicking on any snapshot you have taken in the list of snapshots. By restoring a snapshot, you go back (or forward) in time: the current state of the machine is lost, and *the machine is restored to the exact state it was in when the snapshot was taken.*

So you can safely delete `Baseline` if it's no longer needed.